# Serial Communcation DataRecievedHandler and WPF UI Not In Sync

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I am writing a WPF/C# program that reads data from a weather station and will eventually put it in a MySQL database. The weather station's input to the computer is through a serial port so I am using System.IO.Ports to facilitate the communication.

This is set up so far where I click a button on the UI and it sends the commands to the serial port to have the weather station send data. The issue I am running into involves using the DataRecievedHandler method to handle when data is sent through the serial port to my program. When I get a response back, I get it in the form of a data packet containing 99 bytes, which I read into an array. The issue I am having is that when I try to send that array somewhere else to parse it out, it seems like the array doesn't get completely filled until I press another button on the UI... almost like it waits before finishing filling up the array.

This is the code from the button press in the UI: It sends a wakeup signal "\n"
waits for a bit then sends the signal to get data "LPS 2 1\n"

```
private void button_testSerial_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        wxSerialPort.WriteLine("\n");
        //printArrayList();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        wxSerialPort.Write("LPS 2 1\n");

    }
    catch (Exception C)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please ensure both DB connection and Serial Connections are set up and connected \n \n" + "Error text: \n" + C.ToString(), "Connection Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }

}
```

When I send the wakeup I get first a response of [10], [13] which is correct, this signals the station is awake and returns a buffer with those values.

When I send the next one (LPS 2 1\n)
I can see data come in and if I run a for loop on the array it looks like it has data while the method is running from the button click. The issue is, if I try to send the array from the DataRecievedHandler method to another method or class or such it seems like it doesn't get filled or sent properly. So I end up running into null values in my Byte[] array.

This is my DataRecievedHandler method

```
public void DataRecievedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    byte[] buffer = new byte[wxSerialPort.BytesToRead];
    wxSerialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Buffer length: " + buffer.Length); //test to see if data comes in


    if (buffer.Length == 2) //wake up response is 2 values [10][13]
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Wakeup Response");
        return;
    }

    if (buffer.Length == 0)
    {
        //do nothing and skip
        return;
    }

    else 
    {
        string debugtext = "";
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++) //loop prints out contents for testing
        {

            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine("Buffer Contents " + buffer[i]);
           // Console.WriteLine("ADDING To ArrayList Data: " + buffer[i] + " at position: " + i);
          wxPacketData = buffer; //this is where I assign the Byte[] buffer to an array that can be sent off and parsed

        }

        counter = 0;
        return;
    }

}
```

Finally I send the wxPacketData array (byte array created when the DataReceivedHandler method runs) to another class to be parsed, but this only works if it is clicked from another button, this doesn't work when I have it under the same button as shown above:

```
private void button_parsePacket_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    wxPacketParser wxPacket = new wxPacketParser(wxPacketData);
    wxPacket.parseOutsideHumidity();
    wxPacket.parseOutsideTemperature();
    wxPacket.parseBarometricPressure();
    wxPacket.parseDewPoint();
}
```

The question is, what am I doing wrong so that I have to run the parsing code under a different button click for this to work properly?

I am relatively new to this so if more information is needed please let me know. All suggestions or guidance are very welcome and I appreciate everyone's help in advance. I feel like I'm missing something very simple or basic, but probably need a push to see what that issue is.

Comment: One thing to definitely make sure is that the configuration of Parity and StopBits matches between the device and the COM-Port. If that's not the case you can see all kinds of funky symbols showing up (like your NUL symbols).

Another question is why you are setting the value wxPacketData = buffer inside the for-loop. This should not affect the parsing but doesn't seem to be intended.

Comment: I seem to be getting the data through correctly: Buffer Contents - Position:  [0] Value: 6
Buffer Contents - Position:  [1] Value: 76
Buffer Contents - Position:  [2] Value: 79
... and so on, all 99 values are correct in the array. The strange part is that if I send the array off to another method it never fills until another button is pressed on the UI. If I move the parsing under another button click, it works fine. It almost seems like it waits for something